# Rails + Mysql + Passenger ConnectionTimeoutError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I got this error on my server.
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.701 seconds))

And I search 1 day to solve this problems... But, I do not solve this yet. Many solution are written for Sinatra. I do not find solution for rails.

And my current informations are:

database.yml

```
 production:
   adapter: mysql2
   encoding: utf8
   host: xx.xx.xx.xx
   reconnect: true
   database: test_production
   pool: 100
   timeout: 10000
   wait_timeout: 10000
   username: abc
   password: abc
   socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

And my.conf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
connect_timeout=100
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking


key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8

myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 2048
# max_user_connections   = 1024

table_cache            = 512

thread_concurrency     = 1024

wait_timeout            = 300

#

# * Query Cache Configuration

#

query_cache_limit       = 256M

query_cache_size        = 2566M

#

# * Logging and Replication

#

# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.

# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.

# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!

#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log

#general_log             = 1

#

# Error log - should be very few entries.

#

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log

#

# Here you can see queries with especially long duration

#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

#long_query_time = 2

#log-queries-not-using-indexes

#

# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.

# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about

#       other settings you may need to change.

#server-id              = 1

#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log

expire_logs_days        = 10

max_binlog_size         = 100M

#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name

#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name

#

# * InnoDB

#

# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.

# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!

#

# * Security Features

#

# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!

# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/

#

# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".

#

# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem

# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem

# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

join_buffer_size        = 512K

tmp_table_size          = 512M

max_heap_table_size     = 512M





[mysqldump]

quick

quote-names

max_allowed_packet      = 16M



[mysql]

#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition



[isamchk]

key_buffer              = 16M



#

# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!

#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.

#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

How can I solve this problem..

Comment: are you running your app on the same server with mysql?

Comment: Hello @Zoker. I divided server and mysql. Is there any problems?

Comment: any firewall opened?